# how can i search in mysql database by sending multiple key words by text field using php

Tags: php

1. For example: in a database table there are few columns

   id  pname      pcolor   size       mrp    image . 1    computer
   black    18inch    15000   comp1.jpg 2     cup        silver
   6inch    15      cup.jpg 3    computer    white    12inch    7000
   compt2.jpg

   there is a table like above. now i am going to search a product by
   sending through a text field as bellow:

   search : computers black color.

   how should i get the particular row from data base please tell me
   the code.

   = 1");
       //$result = mysql_query("select * from proddetail where (pname = 'computer')");      
             //or(pKey LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  pname LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  mfg LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  psize LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  mrp LIKE
   '%".$key."%' OR  saleprize LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  pType LIKE
   '%".$key."%' OR  pcolor LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  warranty LIKE
   '%".$key."%' OR  imagename LIKE '%".$key."%')
             //or(pKey LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  pname LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  mfg LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  psize LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  mrp LIKE
   '%".$key."%' OR  saleprize LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  pType LIKE
   '%".$key."%' OR  pcolor LIKE '%".$key."%' OR  warranty LIKE
   '%".$key."%' OR  imagename LIKE '%".$key."%')");      $file_path =
   'http://localhost/ProductDetails/images/';  
         while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             print "
       
       Prod. ID" . $row['pKey'] .
   "
       NAME" . $row['pname'] .
   "
        SIZE" . $row['psize'] .
   " 
         MRP" . $row['mrp'] .
   "
        COLOR" . $row['pcolor'] .
   " 
       
       ";      }   mysql_close($con);
               }
           }?>

   ---

   - Heading

     ## #

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on array_explode and appending query.

```
$keywords = "computers black color";
$array = explode(" ", $keywords);

$query = "select * from computers where";    
foreach($array as $key) {

        $query.= ' table_name_1 LIKE "%'.$key.'%"';
        $query.= ' or table_name_2 LIKE "%'.$key.'%"';
       //more tables here...
}
```

MAKE SURE that you escape values in query!!!